# sparql query for rdf:id

Tags: java, sparql

I want to write a sparql query to get rdf data based on their id. I am trying with

```
SELECT ?ID ?NAME WHERE {?ID = "something" }
```

but does not return the expecting results. Does anyone knows which is my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

Actually rdf:id is the resource URI itself. You can utilise a [SPARQL FILTER](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#termConstraint) clause for filtering your result, or you can directly insert the URI in the WHERE clause of your query, e.g.

```
<myURI> ex:name ?name .
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i tried it with both filter and URI in the where but i can't get any results yet.

Comment: As @castagna already said in his reply, please post some sample RDF data.

Answer (score 2):

In order to have a precise answer you should share a small fragment of your RDF data (possibly in Turtle format, human friendly).